# Creating related tables in mysql database

Tags: mysql

i have a project at hand and it requires me to set up a database to save up product, currently i have product table, color table size table as below

```
color table
colorId(PK)
color
procductId(FK)

size table
sideId(PK)
size
productId(FK)
```

i can relate this 2 tables to product, now my problem is i need to relate color table and size table , take for example i have this following product:
Men's Wicking Polo shirt, this single shirt might have different varieties like different color and different sizes like...

```
 PRODUCT NAME             SIZE         COLOR
 Men's Wicking Polo:      S, M, L      RED GREEN BLUE ORANGE
```

Now my question is: In a situation where there is different color for different sizes say size S is available only in RED and BLUE color, and color GREEN only have size M available while color ORANGE have size S and L available , how do i relate this two table to store this information for easy retrieval

any help on ths will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design you present is problematic. Since none of the tables can serve as the parent table (unless you arbitrarily choose one) you will have trouble referencing one table to the other.
My advice is to create a master table that will include product_id as a PK and then both tables can reference it as a parent. This table will serve as a descriptor to the types of shirts manufactured - containing description of the product, and perhaps other characteristics such as price.

Then, since color and size are references to a certain physical manifestation of the shirt, I would unite them to a single table. That way you can also use this table to store quantity, and get alerted when inventory is running low.

Comment: thanks i got your idea, i have a product table already that has product_id as PK and color id size id as FK also have Qty and so on, anyway i will try another method see if it works  thank you guys for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can use another table `avaible_product_sizes_colors` in which you will have a primary key (productId, sizeId, colorId) which are foreign keys to there respectives tables. You could also store the quantity of avaible products.

Comment: Nice, we had the exact same thought

Comment: thank you guys for your comment, i will try it out and see what i can come up with